# Nginx Rewrite clause with spaces in matched URI

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the URI `'/my url'` to the correct syntax

(dont know why but many incoming queries; also just after I hit enter the URI - at least in the Chrome bas changes to `'/my%20url'`)

`rewrite ^/my url/?$ /my-url permanent;`

But this is not working.

And neither is

`rewrite ^/my%20url/?$ /my-url permanent;`

**Question**: How can I target an URI with spaces and properly redirect it?

Comment: Use: `rewrite "^/my url/?$" /my-url permanent;`

Comment: The reason you're seeing `%20` is because a space is not a valid URL character, hence it gets converted to the hexadecimal representation of its ASCII number; e.g. https://www.asciitable.xyz/ can be used to look up the values. However once received by `nginx` it will be a space again so Richard's comment should work.

Comment: @RichardSmith That did the trick. Please post as anwer and I can approve. The %20 is clear and know this. But! because I saw it changing in front of my eyes I thought the browser changed the uri *before* the server request and sends it in like my%20url in stead of my url. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI is received by Nginx with certain characters [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). However, Nginx [normalizes the URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) before processing it against `location` and `rewrite` statements, so the `%20` has been converted back to a literal space.

To handle expressions with embedded spaces, braces or semicolons, use quotes.

For example:

```
rewrite "^/my url/?$" /my-url permanent;
```